# Invalid syntax with if

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

this is a pretty simple idea, you enter your test score and if you got above a 70% (35/50) you can do corrections for 1 pt back essentially giving you a 100%. If you get under 70% you can do corrections for 1/2 a point back.

this is giving me a invalid syntax and putting the cursor between the last " and )

```
score = input("How many problems did you get right on the test?")
maxscore = 50
passscore = 35
wrong = (maxscore - score)

if (score > passscore):
    print ("You will get a 100%")


if (score < passscore):
    print("You can get"(wrong)"% back  with text corrections")
```

Im terrible at programing so sorry if i seem really stupid here.

Comment: You need to append `wrong` to the other two strings on each side of it.  Using + or ,.  E.g. `print("Hello" + "World") `

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Because `print ("You will get a 100%")` and `input()` function , I think OP is using Python 3.

Comment: What if score is equal to passscore? Plus, how do you feel wrong is a percentage?

Comment: @KevinGuan - Technically, you can use parentheses in a Python 2 `print` statement. Something like `print ('hi')` produces identical results in Python 2 and 3, but `print ('hi', 'there')` produces the tuple `('hi', 'there')` in Python 2 and the string `'hi there'` in Python 3. Also, `input()` exists in Python 2, and will evaluate the entered string into an `int` or `float` or whatever - it's Python 3 that would need to cast the string.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 However usually we use `print 'foobar'` in Python 2 :) And about `print ('hi')` can works on Python 2 because it will create a tuple that only one element in it so the `()` willn't be print out?

Comment: @KevinGuan - Nope, that's not a `tuple`. The parentheses only affect grouping. `1,` is a `tuple`, while `(1)` is an `int`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Got it, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
print("You can get"(wrong)"% back  with text corrections")
```

This is not the correct way to insert a variable into a string. You have several options:

```
print("You can get " + str(wrong) + "% back with text corrections")
```

Or:

```
print("You can get %d%% back with text corrections" % wrong)
```

Or:

```
print("You can get {}% back with text corrections".format(wrong))
```

Or:

```
print("You can get ", wrong, "% back with text corrections", sep='')
```

Also, if you're using Python 3, you'll need to do `score = int(input(...` to cast the string you received as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has to start somewhere (and I'm still pretty new to Python myself)!

Your first problem is that you need to define `score` as an `int`:

```
score = int(input("How many problems did you get right on the test?"))
```

Then there are at least two solutions to fix that last line of code. One is to use `+` to separate your strings of text, plus `str` to convert `wrong` to string format:

```
print("You can get " + str(wrong) + "% back  with text corrections")
```

Or you can use the `.format` approach, which is more "Pythonic":

```
print("You can get {0}% back  with text corrections".format(wrong))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple arguments by comma separating them..

```
print "You can get", wrong, "% back  with text corrections"
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you worry about the syntactic error, you need to transform `wrong` to an `int` because `input()` returns user input as a `str` type.

```
score = int(input("How many problems did you get right on the test?"))
```

If you don't and the user enters a string, the expression:

```
wrong = (maxscore - score)
```

Will raise a `TypeError`, which essentially means that you cannot subtract a value of type `str` (score) from a value of type `int` (maxscore).

---

As for your syntactic error.

```
print("You can get"(wrong)"% back  with text corrections")
```

is syntactically invalid. You need to include `wrong` as a string by transforming it with `str()` in your `print()` call:

```
print("You can get" + str(wrong) + "% back  with text corrections")
```

You can see, conversions between different types, depending on the operation can be a mess until you get a hang of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string concatenated you need to add + between variable names and Strings. Replace your second print line with:

```
print("You can get " + str(wrong) + "% back  with text corrections")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First, `score` must be `int`. So you need use `int()` function to do that.
2. And `if` don't need `()`, just remove them.
3. Then , the problem is about `print("You can get"(wrong)"% back  with text corrections")`, you should use `+` or `,` or `.format()`, etc. here. And remember use `str()` to convert it to string.

---

```
score = int(input("How many problems did you get right on the test?"))
maxscore = 50
passscore = 35
wrong = (maxscore - score)

if score > passscore:
    print("You will get a 100%")


if score < passscore:
    print("You can get "+str(wrong)+"% back with text corrections")
```

This is the simplest way, but use `.format()` will be more clear like this:

```
print("You can get {0}% back  with text corrections".format(wrong))
```

Or like this:

```
print("You can get {wrong}% back  with text corrections".format(wrong=wrong))
```